# Error Deploying GAE Flex Service

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

Using `gcloud app deploy` to deploy a flex service (SDK version 127.0.0), I get the following error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [3] Docker image us.gcr.io/my-project-name/appengine/my-service.20161012t140507:latest was either not found, or is not in Docker V2 format.  Please visit https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/ui

I've checked my container registry, and I can see the image has uploaded and is indeed a v2 image:[image] The logo indicates it's a) the image is there and b) the image is not in v1 format as per https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/ui.

Importantly, I've deployed the exact same service to a different project successfully.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to what to do next - I've already tried 'repairing' my project, as per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps/repair and have re-authed my account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by doing 3 things:

1. Manually giving the "Editor" permission  for your project to the App Engine service account. It's the account with the email like: `<project-id>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`
2. Disabling and re-enabling the Billing API
3. Disable and re-enable the App Engine Admin API.

I suspect that the last one alone should solve the problem, so you're welcome to try it first and give feedback here.

Comment: Thanks for your response Michal. I'd like to start with step 3, but I'm unsure what the `Admin API` is. Where do I find it from the console? Under `IAM & Admin`, or under `API Manager`?

Comment: I did recommended things but it didn't help. :(

Comment: Can verify that for me, fixing 1 alone solved the problem. I had to be a project owner to add the default service account to the IAM list as an editor, then everything worked. Thanks!

Comment: @IgorKhrol Make sure that your project has been linked to an active billing account - this also caused the same error for one of my teammates.