# Error deploying GAE Flex with gcloud app deploy

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible, google-container-registry

All of a sudden having issues with deploying to GCP using `gcloud app deploy`.

Created a brand new project and tried to upload a sample hello-world app from GCP, but still get the following error:

`ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [3] Docker image us.gcr.io/gcp-test-8710371/appengine/default.20181106t173450:latest was either not found, or is not in Docker V2 format.  Please visit https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/ui`

app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

> SDK: Google Cloud SDK 224.0.0

I've checked the container registry, and nothing is created there.

Also, tried enabling/disabling APIs like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40008503/error-deploying-gae-flex-service), but with no result.
An example Python app uploads fine with no problems.

Comment: Looks like an ongoing issue, there are multiple SO posts and a google group post with the same error message.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/vyPukDi50HU

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53180729/gcloud-app-deploy-failed-docker-image-not-found-or-not-in-v2-format

Comment: am facing this again today :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue affecting the Flex deployments. The issue was fixed on 07/11 at aproximately 00:40 UTC. As @isharko pointed out, Flex deployments should be working normally now.

There's also a [public issue on GCP's issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119100369) about this. If new relevant information surfaces, it'll likely be posted there.

Answer (score 2):

Appears it was an issue on GCP's side. The error is no longer occuring, so I assume it was resolved.